# How to retrieve all data from Firebase into one table row in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 textfields in which the user gives 3 inputs.

I want these 3 inputs to be all shown in the same row, but right now my app is showing each value in one row itself.

My JSON consist of the root `BilletSalg` and it contains `tickets` which has 3 keys: `Price`, `TicketName`, `Name`. The values of them are typed by the user in another viewcontroller.

I want the 3 keys to be shown in the same row, but right now I get a row with the `price` value, and then a new row with `ticketName` value, and finally a third row with `Name` value.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

  class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var files: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
func mini() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BilletSalg")
    let usersRef = ref.child("tickets").childByAutoId().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        self.files.append(snapshot)

        print(snapshot)


})
}

let cellNavn = "cellNavn"

  var holes: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []


let CoursesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BilletSalg")





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CoursesRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in




        self.holes = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("tickets").children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    tableView.registerClass(NavnCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellNavn)




}


func handleCancel() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return holes.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellNavn, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NavnCell



   // I want 3 labels to display the 3 values typed by the user, so in each Row you can view the 3 values

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String


 //        cell.textLabel?.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String
 //
  //        cell.anotherlabel.text? = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String


    return cell

    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new swift file UITableViewCell and your tableView prototype cell must be subclass of that UITableViewCell. I guess you have a UITableViewCell named NavnCell. Then you should add labels to your prototype cell in tableview (lets say they are named firstLabel, secondLabel, thirdLabel) and add outlets to them in your UITableViewCell.swift file. Then refer to them in your

> tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

function as cell.firstLabel.text, cell.secondLabel.text and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm sorry! Can you explain it more detailed maybe? I have a UITableViewCell named NavnCell, yes.

Comment: I created another label in my NavnCell file, however it still gets the "first" value in my array, and then populates the next cell with the "second" value in my array. @AtakanCavuslu